# Re-Building Each Tier

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Asp.net project dependency issue (Building each tier seperately)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518692/asp-net-project-dependency-issue-building-each-tier-seperately)

Project1 = Asp.net pages project (presentation Layer)

Project2 = Data Access Layer

when Project1 is hosted and running smooth, if i have to add few PRIVATE methods into the Project2 and call these methods within some of the PUBLIC methods that i know are being called by Project1, should the changes apply that i made in Project2?

I did the above, but the new methods were not called. (I think Project1 is still pointing to the old assemblies of Project2)

I am sure if i rebuild the Project1, the changes will work.

But if i have to rebuild Project1 after every change i make in Project2, what is the point of having the separate tier Architecture? I thought the good thing about separate tiers is that one can do as many changes in 1 layer, without rebuilding the other layers ... is that a wrong perception?