# Asp.net project dependency issue (Building each tier separately)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

Project1 = Asp.net pages project (presentation Layer)

Project2 = Data Access Layer

when Project1 is hosted and running smooth, if i have to add few PRIVATE methods into the Project2 and call these methods within some of the PUBLIC methods that i know are being called by Project1, should the changes apply that i made in Project2?

I did the above, but the new methods were not called. (I think Project1 is still pointing to the old assemblies of Project2)

I am sure if i rebuild the Project1, the changes will work.

But if i have to rebuild Project1 after every change i make in Project2, what is the point of having the separate tier Architecture? I thought the good thing about separate tiers is that one can do as many changes in 1 layer, without rebuilding the other layers ... is that a wrong perception?

Comment: I'm thinking the AppPool hasn't recognized the changes and is using the cached version of the files. Maybe force a restart on the AppPool?

Comment: at the moment i have opened Project1 and 2 in the dev environment on visual studio, so basically when project1 is running in visual studio, using its own IIS, i do changes in Project 2 and rebuild it, then when i do some thing related to the changes on the running website, it doesn't have any effect

Comment: Can you post your code. Your description is hard to parse.

Comment: The _relevant_ code, or at least a minimal replication of the problem.

Comment: The basic question is: if Project1 is referencing Project2, and i have made some changes in Project2 and have rebuild it. do i need to rebuild Project 1 again, for the changes to take affect? Because i have about 6 projects referencing 1 DAL project. Now if i make few changes in a DAL project, do i need to rebuild all 7 projects for the changes to take affect? if yes, then what is the use of separate tier architecture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't HAVE to rebuild it. You can just copy the new project2 dll to the web app\bin directory and it will work if the interface hasn't changed. A build of project1 will redundantly rebuild project1 and produce the same result, and also include the latest version of project2, that's why it works, too.

Comment: hi, thanks. Can you also let me know how do i do that. Normally i just copy the new version of a project and replace it with the older ones. Also all of the projects are Applications of a Default Web Site, sitting some where in the Local Hard Drive, and not in the default wwwroot folder. so where can i find the new DLLs and where to replace them???

Comment: It depends on your IIS settings where your web app actually is. The dll's are under it's bin folder. For project2, the compiled dll's go to project2folder\bin\debug for example.

Comment: rite ... let me try ... i'll be back

Comment: wait ... if i am copying and replacing the full folder, that should replace the debug\xyz.dll , but replacing the full project folder is not working .... do i need to remove Application from IIS and then re-add it?

Comment: you need to compile a fresh project2.dll (which changed), and then copy it to project1\bin folder (where the old version of project2.dll already exists). no need to copy anything else.

Comment: heyyyy.... thank you thank you thank you ...... it is working now, just did exactly as u said in your last comment ... thanks a lot .... Merry Christmas, and Happy New Year ... :)

Answer (score 3):

First of all separate tier doesn't really mean separate assemblies. A multitier archtecture program can easily be stored in 1 assembly and have DAL, presentation and BL classes separated by some logical separator like namespace or even project folders with classes (or even no logical separation whatsoever, but you will known that certain set of classes is for DAl, and annother for BL, etc)

To your question - if your DAL is generic and has a fixed interface  you can update your dal assembly ( for example fix some buggy methods, or something else) if you dont change interface of public methods. Obviously if you change some interface your other assemblies that reference this assembly will have to be not only rebuild but rewritten in order to use new method names for example

Comment: ok...so from what you said i have understood: that as long as the interface is similar to the previous version, and i have just made some bug fixing in the existing methods, i will only need to rebuild and deploy that particular project, and not every other project that references it. am i right? what about if i add a new PRIVATE method in the DAL project, and call it from within the existing PUBLIC method which is called by some of the existing projects in upper tier. should this work? i will not be calling the new method directly from any of the upper tier.

Comment: of-course you can completely rewrite contents of public methods, add all kinds of internal - private calls , to clients from other assemblies those changes wont be seen and wont affect them so you can deploy just 1 assembly. This is a common issue when a big solution has a bug in 1 assembly you simply fix the bug and deploy 1 dll, not everything, which is faster. but you have to be sure you didnt edit public interface anywhere.

Comment: mmm ... i tried that, but it dint work ... may be i was trying it at dev environment, with every solution opened/running in visual studio. Le me test it on real IIS ... I'll be back ...

Comment: hi ... i tried, but it doesn't work. i even restarted my IIS. (I have only made some changes into the method, and did not changer the signature of any method, but its not working)